# AWS: Unable to Ping/SSH instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, ping

I couldn't ping or ssh my AWS instances.

Security Group: 
 --All ICMP allowed from 0.0.0.0/0 
 --SSH allowed 0.0.0.0/0

VPC/Routes/Internet Gateway Target: 0.0.0.0/0

Accessing from Public internet;

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>ping ec2-13-126-227-147.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com


Pinging ec2-13-126-227-147.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com [13.126.227.147] with 32 bytes of data:

Request timed out.


Ping statistics for 13.126.227.147:

Packets: Sent = 1, Received = 0, Lost = 1 (100% loss),

Control-C

^C

C:\WINDOWS\system32>telnet ec2-13-126-227-147.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com 22

Connecting To ec2-13-126-227-147.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com...Could not open connection to the host, on port 22: Connect failed
```

Comment: Lot of information missing. Where are you pinging from? How are you pinging? using public IP or private IP? Care to post the command and output?

Comment: Pinging from public internet. Pinging using Public IP. Output: Request timed out.

Comment: Are you 100% sure your EC2 is residing in the public subnet, aka, the one you have the IGW attached to?

Comment: @fapple Yes. I have one IGW and attached to the subnet

Comment: Internet Gateways don't "attach to" subnets.  They are referenced by routes in route tables, which are associated with subnets.

Answer (score 0):

After further investigation I found the problem is with region ap-south-1.
When I have launched it from different region its working.